# Repeat non-integer values in a sequence

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence of non-integer values where each value is repeated a certain number of times in R. I've tried combining variations of:

```
seq(5,0,by=-0.5)
```

which returns

```
# [1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.0 1.5 1.0 0.5 0.0
```

as well as

```
rep(5:0,each=3)
```

which returns

```
# [1] 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

each of which contains partly what I want, which would look like this:

```
5 5 5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4 4 4 3.5 3.5 3.5 3 3 3 2.5 2.5 2.5 2 2 2 1.5 1.5 1.5 1 1 1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0 0 0
```

It seems that `seq()` contains no "each" analogue, whereas `rep()` contains no "by" argument. Anyone know of a third function that can do both, or a way to combine these two to accomplish my goal? Or, another way alltogether?

Comment: just combine:  `rep(seq(5,0,by=-0.5), each=3)`

Comment: @jalapic, please post as answer!

Comment: Thank you! How I didn't try that I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

Just combine!

```
rep(seq(5,0,by=-0.5), each=3)
```